# Most efficient way to parse the following text

Tags: c#, parsing

**NOTE:** I went with the regex approach. It was very fast so I stuck with that.

Given the following input

```
@class using System.Text.Json
@attribute using System
@attribute using System.Text
@attribute required Type theType
@attribute optional bool IsReadOnly = false
@attribute optional bool SomethingElse
```

I need to create the following objects

```
  new UsingClause(Target.Class, "System.Text.Json");
  new UsingClause(Target.Attribute, "System");
  new UsingClause(Target.Attribute, "System.Text");
  new AttributeProperty(required: true, name: "theType", type: "Type", default: null);
  new AttributeProperty(required: false, name: "IsReadOnly", type: "bool", default: "true");
  new AttributeProperty(required: false, name: "SomethingElse", type: "bool", default: null);
```

Ordinarily I'd split the strings by spaces into an array etc, but this will be used in a Roslyn code generator, so I need it to be as fast as possible.

What approach should I use for this kind of script pre-processing task?

I've started down the route of reading each line using a `StringReader` and then checking it with a compiled `Regex`.  But this whole "ultra efficient" requirement is new to me and I don't want to risk messing it up.

```cs
    private readonly static Regex Regex = new Regex(
      pattern: @"^\s*((@attribute)\s+(using)\s+(.*))|((@attribute)\s+(optional|required)\s+(\w+[\w\.]*)\s+(\w+)(\s*\=\s*(.*))?)|((@class)\s+(using)\s+(.*))\s*$",
      options: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you've suggested? Have you benchmarked it? It is technically not feasible?

Comment: "as fast as possible", do you actually have a performance problem or are you twiddling nanoseconds here?

Comment: It's for a Roslyn compiler, so every CPU cycle counts.  I'm thinking should I be using spans to identify parts of the source string instead of splitting strings, for example?

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on what you consider "efficient" but you should consider writing an ANTLR grammar that would allow the text to be parsed into C# objects which you can then convert to your desired output using something like [Antlr4.Runtime.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard/).

Writing an ANTLR grammar would have the benefit of finding any inconsistencies/ambiguitites in the input 'language'. It would also allow you to add/change capabilities in the future.